# Configuring appengine-web.xml

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-luna

I successfully cloned an web application project from Github to eclipse Luna.
When I try to deploy the cloned project to google app engine, eclipse does not recognise it as a web project. I realised that it was missing the appengine-web.xml file. 
I created one under directory WEB-INF in War, 
I saved it but when I try again to deploy, still eclipse says that the project is not an app engine project.

What could I be possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you do not provide the exact error message, I list several possible causes:

1. Right click on your project, select "Google" option, then "App Engine". Make sure that "Use Google App Engine" checkbox is checked.
2. In your build path, make sure that "Allow output folders for source folders" is checked and the correct folder is specified (i.e. "MyProject/war/WEB-INF/classes".
3. Make sure that you are logged in Google with the correct account before you try to deploy - your current account is shown in the bottom right corner.

UPDATE:

This error indicates that your project is not a Java project. Select Project Facets in Properties. On the right side make sure that on the left side Java 1.7 is selected.

Comment: I have tried step one and the error I get is that "My Project is not an App Engine Project.
Eclipses is logged to google, I have deployed a test project successfully.
I have realised that I don't have the option build path under properties. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I have tried all of the above, yet the message about .xml file not being present persists. Any idea, how I can go about troubleshooting this. The file is already present under WEB-INF folder. I have 2 versions of Java installed and as per the project requirements, I have the Java compiler and compliance set to the correct JDK and JRE.

Comment: @adityah  What is the exact error message that you see?

Comment: Apologies, the comment was posted in mistake (and seems irrelevant). Though, the message is: appengine-web.xml is missing, although the file (appengine-web.xml) is present. Any idea, why eclipse is unable to find it ?

Comment: There is either a problem with folder structure, or maybe there is a problem in the file itself (wrong tag or something).

Comment: @AndreiVolgin will look into it, much appreciated!